# GitLab gitlab-ci.yml colon causing problem with variable

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I keep running into an issue where I need a colon (:) to be input as a string in-between two variables. Specifically I am trying to clone a GitLab repo via:

```
stage: pull-git-repo
script:
  - git clone https://$GL_USER:$GL_TOKEN@gitlab.com/my-repo.git
```

I keep running into two problems:

- GitLAb interprets : as signifying a key:value pair so the documentation suggests encasing the command in '' to make it a string https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html
- I need to reference the variable $GL_USER and $GL_TOKEN. This is fine because I can do a string-escape by encasing the variables in another set of ''.

So in theory this should work:

```
script:
  - git clone 'https://'$GL_USER':'$GL_TOKEN'@gitlab.com/my-repo.git'
```

however when I echo this statement, it effictivly outputs:

**https:my-username:@gitlab.com/my-repo.git**

The token is omitted whereas there should be a value right after the colon. I presume this is because of the first issue with the colon. How the heck do I get around this? (I've also tested the variable is outputting a value when echo'd aloe)

Is there just a better way to authenticate to my gitlab repo when performing a git action within a gitlab pipeline?

Comment: Is the `GL_TOKEN` variable masked? Are you using shared CI runners?

Comment: @N1ngu For testing I have the variable un-masked/protected. Using my own Runner.

Comment: Is the runner updated to the same version deployed in gitlab.com? (From your code excerpt I understand you are using gitlab.com)

Comment: @N1ngu My runner version is 15.9.1 but I'm not sure how that correlates to the web based gitlab.com

Comment: Is your job executing in a bash shell or something else like powershell?

Comment: This can't be reproduced on gitlab.com -- both your given examples work as-is when I tested on gitlab.com using an image running bash shell. [example 1](https://gitlab.com/spyoungtech/test-gitlab-ci-entrypoint/-/jobs/3926731513) and [example 2](https://gitlab.com/spyoungtech/test-gitlab-ci-entrypoint/-/jobs/3926731514) both work.

Comment: You should take good care that the major.minor version of your runner matches the gitlab.com current version, otherwise there are no guarantees of proper functioning: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/#gitlab-runner-versions . It seems you already do, but this needs to be checked.

Comment: Can you ensure there is no typo in the variable name? Is the variable configured to "expand variable reference"? In that case, does its value start with a `$` character?

Comment: It's a containerized linux-based runner (technically docker-in-docker). There's no funny business with the variable containing special chars. I've set the value to "testvariable" just to verify and un-masked it. I can echo the variables consecutively like: echo $var1$var2$var3. The issue is something with placing the vars after https:// or most likely the colon.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU, the single quote encasing is meant for the whole command, because it is first interpreted by a YAML parser.

```
script:
  - 'git clone https://$GL_USER:$GL_TOKEN@gitlab.com/my-repo.git'
```

This will unequivocally be a string and not a map to the eyes of YAML, and that string will be forwarded to the shell executing the script without the enclosing quotes.

Comment: I've tried nearly 50 variations of single and double-quotes including using both to escape each variable from the string. The other variables are interpreted just fine, however the variable following the colon isn't produced. I can wrap the variable following the colon with () or {} and it will show up but obviously that request to gitlab will fail....